# Function has different behaviors in simultaneously calls under stress testing

Tags: java, multithreading, load-testing, stress-testing

I found a bug in a software that only happens under stress testing. A function is massive called and have different behaviors if the calls are simultaneously or almost simultaneously.

I made up an example to illustrate what is happening:

```
public void doPayment(Acccount account) throws MyException {

    if (isMoneyAvailable(account)) {
        confirmPayment(account);
    }else{
        throw new MyException(myErrorCode);
    }
}
```

If this function is called twice simultaneously, two payments are done when the account has money just for one payment.

Do you have any ideas how I can prevent that kind of errors?

Comment: Learn about concurrency and synchronization in Java.

Comment: Quick and dirty solution is to add `synchronized ` keyword to the method signature. But yeah, concurrency should be basic knowledge to any half serious Java programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of synchronised on the entire method, you can synchronize just on the account object. That ways it will perform much better. It is essentially because we do not want multiple threads to access the account object simultaneously. As long as they are accessing different account objects, they should not block each other.

```
public void doPayment(Acccount account) throws MyException {
    synchronized(account){
    if (isMoneyAvailable(account)) {
        confirmPayment(account);
    }else{
        throw new MyException(myErrorCode);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest solution is probably to synchronise it:

```
public synchronized void doPayment(Acccount account) throws MyException {

    if (isMoneyAvailable(account)) {
        confirmPayment(account);
    } else {
        throw new MyException(myErrorCode);
    }
}
```

This would ensure that only one thread can make use of this method in this object at any time.

This may not be what you want. For example, if you have several objects that contain this method (perhaps in a superclass) then you should use a different mechanism.

You should study concurrency and synchronisation to be certain you have it right. Concurrency issues are notoriously difficult to track down.

Answer (score 0):

use Synchronization

```
public void doPayment(Acccount account) throws MyException {
    synchronized(key){
    if (isMoneyAvailable(account)) {
        confirmPayment(account);
    }else{
        throw new MyException(myErrorCode);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Whatever `key` is supposed to be, it seems unnecessary, you can just synchronize on `this`. If you wrap the whole method-body in a `synchronized`, you can synchronize the whole method instead

Comment: @Turing85 but I thought synchronized method is not a good practice

Comment: @Turing85 you synchronize on `this`, and then you end up with two unrelated methods blocking each other in a multithreaded context. Bad advice.

Comment: key should ideally be the account object as described in my answer. I agree with solutions. Just that he failed to mention that key should be the account object

Comment: @akshayapandey Key is not Account object it's just a object.Please review about concurrency and key

Comment: @user7639356 The point I was trying to make is if we synchronize it on the account object. Because, we do not want simultaneous update to amount in the same account object, as long as account objects are different, we should be fine. Also, if the "key" object is always the same for threads,  it does give better performance than putting synchronize at method level. Though, we can do even better by synchronizing on account object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert about multithreading computation but you must consider that there is concurrency on this call as you suggest.
Basically I think that you can simply do this:

```
public synchronized void doPayment(Acccount account) throws MyException {

    if (isMoneyAvailable(account)) {
        confirmPayment(account);
    }else{
        throw new MyException(myErrorCode);
    }
}
```

without knowing anything else of the class that contain this methos, this is my best answer. The difference is in the keyword "syncronized" that permit to java to make "doPayment" call as atomic oparation, so noone can interfere.
For a better explanation for the syncronization, check the java [reference about it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Best regards.